# suggest to add split and combine files from folder

Tags: emeditor

File splitter and combine function of emeditor is very powerful,
but is support opened file and specified file only.

When we have a couple of files need to be splitted or combined.

It's not be able to work .

Can author add this function?

Ready to  buy a lifetime liscense.

Answer (score 0):

You can open all files with EmEditor before you **combine** files. This is partly because EmEditor needs to know exact **file encodings**, and **bookmarks** need to be set after files are open. Opening multiple files is easy and fast with EmEditor. You can select multiple files in the **Open** dialog box, or you can drag and drop multiple files from **Windows Explorer**. **Splitting** files can be already possible without opening files.

Comment: sometimes it's hundreds or thousands of files. and i didn't find a better other tool on this function.  emeditor is extremely fast on combine and split.

Comment: GREAT TO SEE THIS FUNCTION WAS ADDED. I JUST BOUGHT A LISENCE TO THANK YOUR GREAT WORK.

Comment: As you've probably noticed, v20.901 or later allows you to select source files directly (or drag and drop to File Combiner) without opening them first in EmEditor on both File Splitter and Combiner.